# Reverse counting in takewhile()? Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I just wanna ask if it's possible to transform this code into a list comprehension with takewhile()? I'm using python2.7.

I have this code:

```
n=4
c=[]
while n!=0:
    c.append(n)
    n-=1  
print c
```

The output is:

```
[4,3,2,1]
```

I wanted to transform the code into a list comprehension with takewhile()

I tried this but no luck:

```
from itertools import takewhile
n=4
c=[n for n in takewhile(lambda n: n!=0, xrange(n))]
print c
```

Sad to say the output was an empty list:

```
[]
```

I think the cause was that the value on xrange(n) starts with 0 that's why it didn't give my desired output.

Is there a way to reverse the iterator in takewhile (like : starts counting from 4 to 1 instead of 0 to 3?)

Could you give me some advice for this kind of dilemma? I would appreciate it. Let me know if this question has a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xrange can be called as `xrange(1, n+1)` to get the list you want. You can also call it as `xrange (n, 1, -1)` to get the reversed list directly.